# lxml xpath not working

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to parse a webpage code for which is below.
I am able to get the users using the xpath but i am unable to get their scores using xpath any ideas what i am doing wrong here ?

```
import requests
from lxml import html

internsHack = 'https://doselect.com/hackathon/inmobi-internshack/leaderboard'

page = requests.get(internsHack)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

users = tree.xpath('//div[@class="md-list-item-text"]/h2/a/text()')
score = tree.xpath('//div[@class="points-score"]/ng-pluralize/text()')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML source snippet:

```
<div class="points-score">
  <ng-pluralize count="200"
                           when="{'0': '{} point',
                               'one': '{} point',
                               'other': '{} points'}">
</div>
```

Get the `count` attribute values instead of `text()`:

```
//div[@class="points-score"]/ng-pluralize/@count
```

`score` variable would then have the following value:

```
['200', '198', '198', '197', '197', '197', '196', '195', '194', '194']
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but curious to know how did you figure that count is a attribute as when i look for this in developer tools of chrome 200 points is a text item

Comment: @NickLoach what you see in the "Source" in browser developer tools is a rendered page by the browser which can seriously differ from the initial page. What you get with `requests` is the initial unrendered page - this is what you should inspect. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation i examined request content now its illegible but you are correct about the count attribute